# How Can I Convert Int To String In assembly

Tags: variables, assembly, x86-16, tasm

Can I Convert Var(int) like this:

```
var1  db  45
```

That the Var1 will be "45"

Comment: Is this answer helpful to you?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45904076/417501

Comment: i dont think so

Comment: What are you missing?  Simply replace the `int 21h` calls with logic that appends the digit to your string.

Comment: I forgot that Q&A printed digits one at a time instead of storing in a string.  Added more duplicates that do convert to a string.

Comment: Still i didnt get it...